# The simplest way to calculate area of a pentagon

Tags: geometry, area

I have a pentagon, whose all sides and angles I know. What would be the simplest way, i.e requires least calculations, to calculate its area?

If possible, can I generalize your way to higher polygons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach that will work, would be to tediously triangulate the polygon, find all the angles / sides, and then use the sine formula or Heron's formula.

If there are special properties, you might be able to exploit it slightly.

Comment: To find the area of a pentagon, we only need the lengths of its 5 sides and a pair of non-adjacent angles.

Comment: @mick What would be the formula given those 7 values? Would you need to calculate other angles / side lengths?

Comment: Let the pentagon be ABCDE with all sides known, and angles A and C are also known. Areas of ⊿ABE and also ⊿BCD can be found by the area formula - “(1/2)ab sin C”. BD and BE can be found by cosine law. ⊿BED can therefore be found by Heron formula. Sorry that it is not that convenient to include a diagram in the comment.